# Slack - Unable to join external channel

Tags: slack

We have three users.

Two users, User A and User B, were invited by an external user, User C to an external channel and joined just fine.

User A invited me and I joined just fine to this external channel.

Now, User D, who has been with our company for a long time, receives the following message:

[image]

I have researched into this issue for two days now. I have no answer.
As a workaround I have invited User D into this channel, which worked.

I cannot find the proper permission in the Permissions settings. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Please [edit] question to include: 1. Your Slack plan (eg. Free, Pro, Business+, Enterprise). 2. Your   [slack role](https://slack.com/help/articles/360018112273-Types-of-roles-in-Slack). 3. The roles of each of the  3 members of your team.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you know who the owner and admin of the slack account is, it wasn't mentioned in your post.

Verify User D's Account Status: Confirm that User D has the same level of access as User A and User B in your organization. Sometimes, account types or roles can affect external collaboration capabilities.

Review User C's Invite Permissions: Ensure that User C has the necessary permissions in their organization to invite external members to the channel.